# How do I know what version of Firefox I have?

Tags: firefox

Where is the menu in firefox so I can check what my firefox version is?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this so-called 'retarded / Ripped' browser you are running?

Comment: I would also like to see a screenshot of this version of Firefox you're running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can't see the Help menu, run your mouse to the top bar and the menu bar should appear. If you still can't see  the help menu because there are more menus than panel space permits, use the arrow keys to navigate between menus. Then, you can see the help menu.

By the way, the keyboard shortcut for accessing the menubar is <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Answer (score 17):

Also, you can obtain firefox version through command line

```
firefox --version
```

or equivalently

```
firefox -v
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see the menus in Ubuntu simply by pressing and holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, they will be integrated in the global menu bar on top.

It will also show if you hover over it.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the menu there is a small question mark, which when clicked opens a help menu sidebar!

Running: 
`Xubuntu 14.04`  and `Firefox 32.0`

[image: menu showing question mark]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers you could as well use a more general approach and ask your operating system itself what it has installed

```
apt-cache policy firefox
```

This outputs the full name of the ubuntu package.

Example: `46.0+build5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2`